# Getting special character in FastExport script

Tags: teradata

```
   sel cast(trim(Env) as char(6)) ,
    cast (trim(Databasename) as char(30)) from DB.Top_Space_Consumer;
```

I am running above query through fast export and getting data in below format.

```
%^@^@PKPTD DB1
%^@^@PKPTD DB2
%^@^@CLPTD DB3
%^@^@PKPTD DB4
```

i want data in below format.

```
PKPTD DB1
PKPTD DB2
CLPTD DB3
PKPTD DB4
```

As the size of the table is "big" a few Gigabytes, i can't open it with a text editor in order to remove the characters.

**The question is:** 
What should i change in the script in order not to obtain this "extra characters"?

Comment: This is a valid question that may not have been asked with the enough clarity for the general audience. If you are still having trouble with this FastExport try reposting your question with more details and I can try to help you.

Comment: The same has been happening to me. I don't see what's not clear in the question?

Comment: I think it's clear, too. Rob's answer to switch to TEXT output will be ok, but then it's fixed width with lots of blanks. If you want delimited output it's better to use TPT, the latest releases finally added VARTEXT output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing your export format is FASTLOAD or BINARY. FastExport appends two binary bytes of data to the beginning of each record.

To get around this in the past I have concatenated the fields together with the delimiter of choice and casted the datatypes to a character and then casted the record to a fixed length. This does mean there is trailing white space at the end but that can be easily accounted for when loading the data into the next environment. Then you can change your export format to TEXT and the binary data will not be appended to the beginning of your records.